# How to retrieve column in sequence on SQLite using R

Tags: r

I uses a censor data which provide the wavelengths from 100-300nm with sequence 1, means: 100, 101,102,103,..300. I keep the data in SQLite using R, with table name as `data`

```
> data
 obs   100  101  102  103  104  ...  300
   1   0.1  0.1  0.9  0.1  0.2       0.5
   2   0.8  1.0  0.9  0.0  1.0       0.4
   3   0.7  0.8  0.3  0.8  0.5       0.2
   4   0.7  0.1  0.2  0.4  0.7       0.6
   5   0.9  0.4  0.6  0.6  0.6       0.4
   6   0.7  0.1  0.6  0.7  0.9       0.9
```

I am interested to retrieve the column number with sequence 4 only starting 100. Means: 100, 104, 108, ...

I tried using `sqldf("select 100, 104, 108, ... from data")` but seems not efficient work. Is there someone can help using R? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use paste() inside of sqldf to make things like this easier. So the basic idea would be:

```
sqldf(paste("select",
            paste0("`",seq(100,300,4),"`",collapse=", "),
            "from data"))
```

Columns or tables with numeric names typically need to be surrounded with backticks. So that's why I've adjusted the statement to find `100`, instead of 100.

The full statement (simplified above) looks like this:

```
[1] "select `100`, `104`, `108`, `112`, `116`, `120`, `124`, `128`, `132`, `136`, 
            `140`, `144`, `148`, `152`, `156`, `160`, `164`, `168`, `172`, `176`, 
            `180`, `184`, `188`, `192`, `196`, `200`, `204`, `208`, `212`, `216`, 
            `220`, `224`, `228`, `232`, `236`, `240`, `244`, `248`, `252`, `256`, 
            `260`, `264`, `268`, `272`, `276`, `280`, `284`, `288`, `292`, `296`, 
            `300` from data"
```

Comment: Thanks @www for your answer, its work!. Any way if it is not in SQLite, means I want to just run a small data let say `data<-read.csv("test.csv", header=TRUE)` with column name the same `100, 102, ..., 300`. How I can choose the data frame from spesific column name with sequence 4? I tried here but not working, `new<-data[,c(paste0("'X",seq(550,555,2),"'",collapse=",")))`

Comment: @Honstel - If the data is already in R and you're using read.csv, which will add X to the start of each numeric column name, then you can use something like: data[,c(paste0("X",seq(100,104,4)))]

Answer (score 0):

sqldf loads the gsubfn package which provides `fn$` for dealing with string interpolation.  `fn$` can preface any function invocation so, for example, use `fn$sqldf("... $var ...")` and then `$var` is replaced with its value.

Note that `select 100` selects the number 100 and not the column named 100 so we use `select [100]` instead.

```
cn <- toString(sprintf("[%d]", seq(100, 300, 4)))   # "[100], [104], ..."
fn$sqldf("select $cn from data")
```

or if we want to create the SQL statement in a variable and then run it:

```
sql <- fn$identity("select $cn from data")
sqldf(sql)
```

Note that this is pretty easy to do in straight R as well:

```
data[paste(seq(100, 300, 4))]
```